# VERY ODD: android: java.util.logging.Logger.removeHandler throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android

#### NOTE!!!

this exception is NOT thrown by the for-each iterator you see in the posted codes!!!

i've encountered a very odd ConcurrentModificationException in my android app.

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public MyApp extends Application {
    private static final Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
    @override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ......
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            rootLogger.removeHandler(handler);
        }
        rootLogger.addHandler(rootHandler);
        rootLogger.setLevel(fileLogLevel);
    }
}
```

in very occasional cases, when I start the app by clicking desktop icon, there's the exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
E/AndroidRuntime(26111): at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(26111): at java.util.logging.Logger.updateDalvikLogHandler(Logger.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(26111): at java.util.logging.Logger.updateDalvikLogHandler(Logger.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(26111): at java.util.logging.Logger.removeHandler(Logger.java:486)
```

#### NOTE!!!

this exception is NOT thrown by the for-each iterator you see in the posted codes!!!

there's no concurrency access for `Application.onCreate()`.

here's the source code for your reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-6.0.1_r54/luni/src/main/java/java/util/logging/.

I strongly recommend you reading the source code, which MUST helps to understand what i explain as following.

#### === this is what i have researched for the exception ===

let's get to here `Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();` in the first code block. the implementation of `Logger.getHandlers()` is:

```
public Handler[] getHandlers() {
    return handlers.toArray(EMPTY_HANDLERS_ARRAY);
}
```

and the core part of `Logger.removeHandler(Handler)` is, in Logger.java:

```
private final List<Handler> handlers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Handler>();
public void removeHandler(Handler handler) {
    ......
    this.handlers.remove(handler);
    updateDalvikLogHandler();
}
```

so we can see that the exception is not thrown by `logger.removeHandler(handler);` posted in the first code block.

let's dive into the exception trace. the exception is at Logger.java:

```
for (Logger logger : children) { // this line in crash trace
    logger.updateDalvikLogHandler();
}
```

and this is the last entry of the exception trace, in ArrayList.java:

```
public E next() {
    ArrayList<E> ourList = ArrayList.this;
    int rem = remaining;
    if (ourList.modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    ......
}
```

the exact reason for the exception is that `Logger.children` is modified somewhere when calling `for (Logger logger : children)`.

comments of Logger.java says all its methods are thread safe.

#### === end of my explaination, start of my questions ===

i'm totally confused what happend to `Logger.children` which is modified in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-6.0.1_r54/luni/src/main/java/java/util/logging/LogManager.java. but my code does not call `LogManager`.

i believe i need someone helping me to clarify my thinking, and helps to find the bug.

many thanks for reading the long post...

Comment: Create a copy of the array/list like `new ArrayList<>(handlers)`. You should not remove from a collection as you iterate through it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows the exception is not thrown from the foreach i posted, please read the `NOTE!!!`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post comments so I will post this as an answer.

Is the exception thrown if you comment the for-each code?

I suspect the exception is thrown because you are modifying `logger` after doing `logger = rootLogger` somewhere else in your code and the system is modifying it too.

Comment: `rootLogger` is only accessed where i posted... i've searched the project.

Answer (score 0):

In [java.util.logging.Logger.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-6.0.1_r54/luni/src/main/java/java/util/logging/Logger.java):

```
/**
 * Child loggers. Should be accessed only while synchronized on {@code
 * LogManager.getLogManager()}.
 */
final List<Logger> children = new ArrayList<Logger>();
```

The loop over children in `Logger.updateDalvikLogHandler()` is obviously called without needed synchronization.

```
for (Logger logger : children) {
    logger.updateDalvikLogHandler();
}
```

You are probably creating loggers in other classes e.g.

```
static final LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName())
```

which in turn updates Logger.children property.

This can be called from other than main thread. When You use MyClass from other thread, static field initialisation will create new logger that will update children property of root logger.

In this case I consider it a bug in Logger to use children property without synchronising to LogManager.

Workaround would be to call logging initialisation in synchronised block

```
synchronized (LogManager.getLogManager()) {
    Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
    for (Handler handler : handlers) {
        rootLogger.removeHandler(handler);
    }
    rootLogger.addHandler(rootHandler);
    rootLogger.setLevel(fileLogLevel);
}
```